# Find the maximum value or fine upper bound of the maximum of the following function

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, real-numbers

I meet up with the following function and I failed to find its maximum of it.
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+1}} + \sqrt{\frac{x}{x+\alpha}}\right)^2
$$
where $\alpha > 1$ is a constant.

By far, I can only shows that the maximum exists and it is achieved between 1 and $\alpha$.
I want to ask if there is a solution to find the maximum mathematically. Or if there is a fine upper bound for the maximum. I try to develop an upper bound for it by considering

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+1/x}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\alpha/x}}\right)^2 < \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2/\sqrt{x}}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\sqrt{\alpha}/\sqrt{x}}}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{\alpha}}\right)^2$$
But this bound is too large for my case.

Appreciate if I can get some hints from you.

Thanks for all the answer. I provides some of my calculation here.

If I denote
$$
f_{\max}(\alpha) = \max_{x>0}f(x)
$$
I can develop an estimation that
$$
\frac 1 2 + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\alpha}} + \sqrt{\frac{2}{\alpha+1}} \leq f_{\max}(\alpha) \leq \frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{\alpha}}\right)^2
$$
and the inequality is the equal one only if $\alpha = 1$.

However for my case the upper bound is a little bit larger and I wonder if there is a finer one especially near $\alpha =1$. Thanks for the asymptotic solution provided by @[Claude Leibovici](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/82404/claude-leibovici). It gives me some idea and the order estimation provided by @[TeM](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/247735/tem).

Comment: For small values of $\alpha$ you cannot expect much better estimate than you have. Indeed $f(\alpha)\ge {1\over 2\sqrt{\alpha}}.$

Comment: Yes, you are right. So how about consider the case when $\alpha > 1$. It should be a finer upper bound for the maximum.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x>0$ you can very quickly arrive to the equation to be solved if you write instead
$$f(x)=\frac1{\sqrt x}\left(\frac{\sqrt x}{\sqrt{x+1}}+\frac{\sqrt x}{\sqrt{x+a}}\right)^2=\sqrt{x} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+a}}\right)^2$$ After simple simplification
$$f'(x)=\frac{\left(\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x+a}\right)^2}{2 \sqrt{x} (x+1)^2
   (x+a)^2}\,\left(\color{red}{a(1-x)+x \left(2 \sqrt{x+1} \sqrt{a+x}-3
   x-1\right)}\right)$$
One step of squaring leads to the quartic equation
$$5 x^4+2 (a+1) x^3+\left(a^2-8 a+1\right) x^2-2 a (a+1)
   x+a^2=0$$ already given by @TeM in his/her answer.

$\forall~a~>~1$, there are always two real solutions but one of them needs to be discarded since it gives $x=\frac 15$ if $a=1$ instead of $x=1$; morover, this solution is an increasing function of $a$ making $x$ to go asymptotically to $1^-$.

The retained solution goes through a maximum value of $x=2$ for $a=10$ giving $f(2)=\frac{3}{2 \sqrt{2}}$ while the maximum maximorum of $f(x)$ is $2$ for $a=x=1$.

Using asymptotic analysis
$$f_{\text{max}}(x)=\frac12 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n\, t^n \qquad \text{where}\qquad t=\sqrt{\frac 2 a}$$ the first coefficients being
$$\left\{1,\frac{3}{4},\frac{1}{8},-\frac{9}{16},-\frac{165}{128},-\frac{57}{32},-\frac{1219}{1024},\frac{591}{256},\cdots\right\}$$

**Edit**

Since we have the analytical solution of $x$, we can make its series expansion around any value of $a$.

For example, as you asked in comments, around $a=1$
$$f_{\text{max}}(x)=2+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\,b_n\, t^n \qquad \text{where}\qquad t=\frac {a-1}2 $$ the first coefficients being
$$\left\{1,\frac{9}{8},\frac{25}{16},\frac{309}{128},\frac{1017}{25
   6},\frac{3489}{512},\frac{3081}{256},\frac{711645}{32768},\frac
   {2610877}{65536},\cdots\right\}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your asymptotic solution provides a guide for my estimation. May I ask how to achieve your coefficients or it there is a formula for the $n$-th coefficients ?

Comment: @RomeoLiu. It is a very tedious process : have the analytic solution of the solution of $f'(x)=0$ (very long). Plug it in $f(x)$ to get several pages of output and then asymptotic analysis. No way to get any formula for the coefficients.

Comment: Another question: You achieved asymptotic solution when $a\rightarrow +\infty$. What is the situation if I need the asymptotic behaviour when  $a\rightarrow 1$ ? I am interested in the order near $a=1$. Thanks again !

Comment: @RomeoLiu. Have a look at the edit

Comment: Great thanks! May I ask how do you calculate it? I try to use Mathematica but it failed to provides me the result.

Comment: Since you use Mathematica , it is simple. Ask for the solution of the quartic equation. Take the last one as $x$. Plug in $f(x)$. Ask for the series.

Answer (score 0):

Setting $\alpha>0$ and given the function $f:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ of law:

$$
f(x) := \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+1}}+\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+\alpha}}\right)^2
$$

the first factored derivative is:

$$
f'(x) = \frac{\left(\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x+\alpha}\right)^2\left(2x\sqrt{x+1}\sqrt{x+\alpha}-3x^2-(\alpha+1)x+\alpha\right)}{2\sqrt{x}(x+1)^2(x+\alpha)^2}.
$$

So, provided that:

$$
3x^2+(\alpha+1)x-\alpha>0
\quad \Leftrightarrow \quad
x > \frac{-(\alpha+1)+\sqrt{\alpha^2+14\alpha+1}}{6}
$$

proceeding by squaring, we have:

$$
f'(x) = 0
\quad \Leftrightarrow \quad
x^4 + \frac{2(\alpha+1)}{5}x^3 + \frac{\alpha^2-8\alpha+1}{5}x^2 - \frac{2\alpha(\alpha+1)}{5}x + \frac{\alpha^2}{5} = 0
$$

where among the four roots only one will satisfy the previous condition.

In particular, by substituting $x = y - \frac{\alpha+1}{10}$, we reduce to the depressed form:

$$
y^4 + \underbrace{\frac{7\alpha^2-86\alpha+7}{50}}_{p}\,y^2 + \underbrace{\frac{-4(\alpha+1)^3}{125}}_{q}\,y + \underbrace{\frac{17\alpha^4+268\alpha^3+2502\alpha^2+268\alpha+17}{10000}}_{r} = 0
$$

and the only acceptable root turns out to be:

$$
y = \frac{\sqrt{s_1}+\sqrt{s_2}}{2}
$$

with:

$$
\begin{aligned}
& s_1 \equiv \frac{s_3 - 2p}{3}\,; \\
& s_2 \equiv -\frac{s_3 + 4p}{3} - \frac{2q}{\sqrt{s_1}}\,; \\
& s_3 \equiv \sqrt[3]{\frac{s_4}{2}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{s_4}}\left(p^2+12r\right); \\
& s_4 \equiv \left(2p^3+27q^2-72pr\right) + \sqrt{\left(2p^3+27q^2-72pr\right)^2-4\left(p^2+12r\right)^3}\,.
\end{aligned}
$$

In conclusion, if $\overline{x}$ locates the maximum point, then $f\left(\overline{x}\right)$ is the desired maximum:

[image]

function that can be fit with:

$$
\tilde{f}_{\max} = 0.5 + \frac{1.7}{\alpha^{0.5}}
$$

from which:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer ! Your answer provides an order estimation for the maximum. But as you can see, if I want to develop a bound near $\alpha=1$, I have to make a more accurate estimation near $1^-$.